# Set ListView row height in code

Tags: android, listview, button, height

I have an `Activity` containing a `ListView` based on `SimpleCursorAdapter` and a button.
When I click the button, I want the row height to get bigger.
I decided to use `TextView` height for this on button `OnClick`:

```
TextView tvRow = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvRow);
tvRow.setHeight(20);
```

but it changes only the first row of the list.

I can change the height in the `Adapter`'s `getView` method:

```
TextView tvRow = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvRow);
tvRow.setHeight(20);
```

but that's not the functionality I need; I need this on button `OnClick`.

How can I change `ListView` Row height by tapping a button?
Maybe even a trick :)
Thank you for your time.

**UPDATE:**

When I put this code in `SimpleCursorAdapter` everything works fine, but in method `getView` in `BaseAdapter`:

```
@Override
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
   View view = convertView;
if (view == null) {
  view = lInflater.inflate(R.layout.itemF, parent, false);
}
...   
 final LayoutParams params = view.getLayoutParams();
            if (params == null) { 
                view.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, mRowHeight)); 
        }else { 
        params.height = mRowHeight; }
return view;
```

the list at display just ignores this and its row width stays the same. What is wrong?

**UPDATE:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/llRow"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/cbBox"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/llRow1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingTop="5dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvName"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Наименование фирмы"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textSize="14dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvAddr"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Адрес фирмы"
        android:textSize="10dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: So you want all of the rows to get bigger when you click the button?

Comment: your second piece of code is the same as your first, is this a typo?

Comment: yes, I want all rows be the same size - bigger or smaller.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I think you must chage [getView()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html#getView%28int,%20android.view.View,%20android.view.ViewGroup%29) method of your `SimpleCursorAdapter`, like this:

```
final SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter (context, cursor) {
    @Override
    public View getView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        final TextView text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvRow);
        final LayoutParams params = text.getLayoutParams();

        if (params != null) {
                params.height = mRowHeight;
        }

        return view;
    }
}
```

When you click on your button, you must change `mRowHeight` and notify `ListView` about changes like `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`. For the first value of `mRowHeight` you can set this:

```
mRowHeight = LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
```

**UPD:**

If method [hasStableIds()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#hasStableIds%28%29) of your `BaseAdapter` return `false` (it return `false` as default) you must apply little changes in your `getView()` (you must set `LayoutParams` to your `View` manually):

```
LayoutParams params = view.getLayoutParams();
if (params == null) { 
    params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, mRowHeight); 
} else {
    params.height = mRowHeight;
}

view.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Comment: @Foenix, It depends on which layout is the parent of the View. But ViewGroup.LayoutParams in all cases may be suitable.

Comment: I would advise you to change the height of your final View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent). But in first initialization his LayoutParams can be null, that' why you can doin like this: if (params == null) {
                view.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT), mRowHeight)
        } else {
                params.height = mRowHeight;
        }

Comment: that is much better because row can consist of several other views, thank you again!

Comment: @Foenix, you need to change width or height (the updated question says about the width)? Can you add full code of itemF.xml and method getView(), please.

Comment: It was all about row height, not width.I updated the post with xml, method getView was already full. Today I noticed that row height WAS changed but in a strange way - all rows in the screen stay the old height, but when I scroll down the list all rows beneath change their height right way.

Comment: @Foenix, I think problem was in set LayoutParams. I update answer.

Comment: I wish I could be just a little as smart as you. Thank you very much, it works like a miracle :)

Answer (score 5):

I did something like that :

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView,ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

        TextView textView=(TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
        textView.setHeight(30);
        textView.setMinimumHeight(30);



        / * Couleur de votre choix * / 
        textView . SetTextColor ( Couleur . BLACK );



        retourner voir ; 
    }
```

You must put both fields textView.setHeight (30); textView.setMinimumHeight (30); or it won't work. For me it worked, & i had the same problem.