# Setting height of views inside a ListView-Item

Tags: android, listview, layout

I have a `ListView`. Each item should contain a bar chart which I create out of several `TextView`-Objects.
Here is one for a single bar.

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/viewMon"
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="#53933f" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="@string/chart_mon"
            android:textAlignment="center" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

In the `getView`-Method of my Adapter, I try to calculate the height of this element and finally set it via

```
TextView dayView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.viewMon);
dayView.setHeight(height);
```

The problem is that this seems to have no effect. The values should be correct and if I set the values as text I see them apperaing in the UI.

For me it seems that the system ignores layout parameters (`getHeight` also returns 0) and uses the values form the xml-file at another place. How can I avoid this?

Comment: Try to set android:minHeight="whateverdp" to RelativeLayout.

Comment: use android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight" here is more details http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2009/02/android-layout-tricks-1.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13711018/set-listview-row-height-in-code-solved).

Instead of simply setting heigth via `setHeight`, I use this:

```
LayoutParams params = dayView.getLayoutParams();
if (params == null) { 
   params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, heights[x]); 
   } else {
   params.height = heights[x];
        }
   dayView.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code snippet-

```
   yourviewforgetheight.ViewTreeObserver vto = text_about_content.getViewTreeObserver();
                vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onGlobalLayout() {

    yourviewforgetheight.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
                float height =yourviewforgetheight.getHeight();
    TextView dayView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.viewMon);
    dayView.setHeight(height);

                    }
                });
```

Hope this code helps you!!!
if it is not working please let me know i will try to help you more.